# maven repositories order

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven repo which stores all the artifacts  under

http://example.com/content/public

I have a second repo which stores different artifacts under

http://example.com/content/type1

By default for all the builds I want to get the artifacts from "content/public"

But for one specific usecase when a flag is switched on I want to get artifacts from "content/type1"

If an artifact is not present then I want to look for it in "content/public"

My apache-maven/3.04./conf/settings.xml looks like this

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!-- This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*,!type1</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://example.com/content/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!-- Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!-- all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                  <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy></snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <properties>
            <!-- Default this property so we can create references easily. -->
            <nexusHostName>example.com</nexusHostName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <!-- make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

My profile in the pom.xml looks like this

```
<profile>
        <id>type1-build</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>type1</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>type1</id>
                <name>Type1 Repo</name>
                <url>http://${nexusHostName}/content/groups/type1/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <!-- Enforce strict checksums and always update releases and snapshots -->
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>nexus</id>
                <name>Nexus</name>
                <url>http://${nexusHostName}/content/groups/public/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <!-- Enforce strict checksums and always update releases and snapshots -->
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

    </profile>
```

Even after doing this when i run a goal like mvn goal1 -Dtype1=true it still looks for artifacts in "content/public"

Can someone please tell me what is that I am doing wrong

Comment: Why do you want to change the order for just 1 artifact? maven will check other repos if not found in one repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of your repositories content/type1 first and then content/public